# How do I run Spark 2.2 on YARN and HDP?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to run Spark 2.2 with HDP 2.6. I stop Spark2 from Ambari, then I run:

```
/spark/bin/spark-shell --jars 
/home/ed/.ivy2/jars/stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models.jar,/home/ed/.ivy2/jars/jersey-bundle-1.19.1.jar --packages 
databricks:spark-corenlp:0.2.0-s_2.11,edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.6.0 
\--master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 4g --executor-cores 2 --num-executors 11 --conf spark.hadoop.yarn.timeline-service.enabled=false
```

It used to run fine, then it started giving me:

`17/12/09 10:16:54 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.`

I can run it OK, without `--master yarn --deploy-mode client` but then I get the driver only as executor.

I have tried `spark.hadoop.yarn.timeline-service.enabled = true`.

`yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled` and `pmem` are set to false.

Can anyone help or point me where to look for errors? TIA!

PS spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
spark.eventLog.dir hdfs:///spark2-history/
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
spark.history.fs.logDirectory hdfs:///spark2-history/
spark.history.kerberos.keytab none
spark.history.kerberos.principal none
spark.history.provider org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider
spark.history.ui.port 18081
spark.yarn.historyServer.address master.royble.co.uk:18081
spark.yarn.queue default
spark.yarn.jar=hdfs:///master.royble.co.uk/user/hdfs/sparklib/*.jar
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Dhdp.version=2.6.0.3-8
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -Dhdp.version=2.6.0.3-8
spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions -Dhdp.version=2.6.0.3-8
```

I've also tried the `Dhdp.version=` fixes from [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/41710/spark-job-failing-could-not-find-or-load-main-clas.html).

Comment: Interestingly it warns: `17/12/09 10:26:46 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
` even though I thought I had set this.

Comment: Can you remove `--driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 4g --executor-cores 2 --num-executors 11` and start over? YARN might not have enough resources for the Spark app.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that: same error.

Comment: Not intending to start a political discussion, but with Cloudera the installation is really simple. I just did on CDH 5 with Spark 2.2 and took me about 20 minutes and all runs fine. Just saying.

Comment: But to add something of value, I have seen that error before and restarting my cluster services helped.

Comment: @xmorera CDH is tempting if it's still free, but I don't have long and I found in the past getting CDH or HDP to work takes a long time. I've tried restarting many times.

Comment: I've just noticed HDP 2.6.3 has Spark 2.2. So I'll try and upgrade to that, God help me!

Comment: @schoon long story short, CDH is free with unlimited scalability. The part that you pay for is when you want support directly from Cloudera or some of the more advanced monitoring and security. About setting them up, I have a few courses in Pluralsight that show you how to deploy a dev cluster, a prod cluster, a cluster in AWS and then working with the projects via HUE if you are interested in learning more you can see them here: http://tiny.bigdatainc.org/cdhso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to HDP 2.6.3 and it now works.